# AngularJS Filter Template Binding Syntax - Not like docs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, syntax, angularjs-filter

So when browsing the angularJS docs I notice that various filter templates are like this:

> {{ date_expression | date : date : format}}

What is the meaning of date : date?

If I run the following code:
(JS Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6Jt4h/2/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCon">    
    {{dt1 | date : 'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}<br>
    {{dt1 | date : dt1 : 'MM/dd/yyyy @ h:mma'}}
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);    
testApp.controller('testCon', function($scope) {
    $scope.dt1 = new Date();
});
```

I get the following output:

```
03/20/2014 @ 3:19PM
T3u 3PMr 20 2014 15:19:46 G3T-0500 (CentrPMl DPM2014lig3t Ti19e)
```

Why does the second line not work correctly, even though it appears to be property following the syntax?

Am I to understand that the correct syntax is:

> {{ date_expression | date : format}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be correct. The documentation is wrong, and the correct syntax is in fact `{{date_expression|date:format}`.

Some background on this error: filters in Angular are implemented as basic functions, so you could imagine it as something like `function date(date, format)`. However, when used as a filter, the *first* parameter is actually the value *before* the pipe. (in this case, `data_expression`)

You should [submit a pull request to improve this doc](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/edit/master/src/ng/filter/filters.js). Otherwise I will and I'll take the credit for finding the issue :)

Comment: I poked around creating a pull request, but I did not see where that "Usage" template is generated. I think it's just a bug in the way the "Usage" section is automatically generated, not in the documentation itself.